# flex4 add group with transition effect

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

How can i add a Group (with unknown size) to SkinnableContainer with a transformation effect?

**Example** 
First, resize the SkinnableContainer smoothly to its final size and then fade in the Group.

**Problem hereby** 
The Group-size is determined by adding it to the SkinnableContainer. Doing this, the SkinnableContainer gets the final size and the Group is shown, without playing the transition effect.

All examples i found are MXML- and State-based. But i need an **Actionscript-only** solution here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <fx:Declarations>
    <s:Parallel id="showEff">
        <s:Rotate3D angleYFrom="-90" angleYTo="0" duration="7000"/>
        <s:Fade alphaFrom="0.0" alphaTo="1.0" duration="7000" />
        <mx1:WipeRight duration="9000"/>
    </s:Parallel>

    <s:Parallel id="hideEff">
        <s:Rotate3D angleYFrom="0" angleYTo="-90" duration="4000" />
        <s:Fade alphaFrom="1.0" alphaTo="0.0"  duration="7000"/>
        <mx1:WipeRight duration="5000"/>
    </s:Parallel>
</fx:Declarations>


    <s:Button id="btn"
              label="Toggle Panel visibility"
              click="skinnableContainerPanel.visible =      !skinnableContainerPanel.visible;" />

 <s:Panel id="skinnableContainerPanel" title="Using SkinnableContainer" 
         width="500" height="300" showEffect="{showEff}"
         hideEffect="{hideEff}" >
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout  gap="10" verticalAlign="middle" 
                           horizontalAlign="center"/>
    </s:layout>
<s:SkinnableContainer
    skinClass="com.SkinnableContainerSkin" 
    width="50%" height="50%" horizontalCenter="0"
    verticalCenter="0">
    <s:HGroup horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"  >
        <s:BorderContainer width="50" height="50"  
                           borderWeight="2"   color="0x323232" />
        <s:BorderContainer width="50" height="50"  
                           borderWeight="2" color="0x323232" />
        <s:BorderContainer width="50" height="50" 
                           borderWeight="2" color="0x323232" />
    </s:HGroup>
</s:SkinnableContainer>
</s:Panel>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! but i really need a **actionscript only** solution. the content i talk about is generated dynamically, depending on what comes from the server.